# High httpd.exe usage for every CakePHP 1.3 page request

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

We got a company to help us build a CRM of sorts in Cakephp 1.3. It has multiple models/controllers/views, of course and interacts with a MySQL db.

The engagement with the company turned sour and we just realised that 'every' request to this server causes a CPU spike of around 20-60% for 1-2seconds on a 1.6Ghz Dual core PC. We switched to nginx and the php process here also takes similar CPU power (on both Windows and Ubuntu systems).

Now, I've gone through the code..while some pages are understandably tedious (with a model being loaded in Controller, and a view with one 'foreach' loop with a nested 'foreach' loop in it), some pages like the roles_controller.php has only 3 roles has simply has to list the users in the view! I've even disabled the 'foreach' loop in the view (commented out everything) but it still takes that much CPU.

Is it something to do with the dispatcher/routes configuration? We can't cache most of our data as its an internal tool (taxi bookings) and has to serve only the latest data. I've reset the /cake directory to original but no avail.

Summing up, I'd like to know if this is common in all Cakephp or even PHP setups..and if not, how do I go about tracing what is causing the high CPU usage..?

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing anything about the innards of the CRM app itself it's very difficult to say, but the suspicion has to be on the app's code itself.  If it's doing a lot of expensive operations (DB access, remote server access, etc), especially in loops, then it's going to cause a big CPU hit regardless of the HTTPD being used. It might also be consuming more memory than the server has, causing it to page out which is also slow and expensive. I'd suggest profiling your CRM app.

Comment: I profiled it using x-debug & webgrind and found that every Html->link was using up at least 20ms. And I had over a 100 of these..

Comment: @Redd: Does every page load do select on a database? Does the database behind it have primary keys? Are then being used? Are there needless loops?

Comment: I'd say it's more likely a PHP issue than a database issue as otherwise you see a spike on the mysqld process as well/instead. You can verify this by enabling slow query logging in MySQL or just installing mysql-top and looking at how long the queries are taking.

Comment: @james-geldart No MySQL spikes..its CakePHP alright. Even on a fresh cake install, there are CPU spikes on EVERY request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track execution times on executing functions and loops to determine which one exactly causing such a big load. test one by one.
As previously mentioned, this definitely caused by PHP/Apache under httpd process, not remote connections... networking is not in this story.

after you determine the bottleneck, you can post the function here, so we can help you optimizing it.

I just investigates the html->link, seems nothing performance harmful, but on the way i seen some function named 'clean', that filtering output and performing a lot of regexes, and i can say this may cause the slowdown, just depends on amount of html, if i does not mistake :)
The point here that RegEx is just performance eater, and the _output preforms 12 such regexes.
File location: cake/libs/view/helper.php
Line number: 880-912
Function code:

```
/**
 * Removes harmful content from output
 *
 * @return void
 * @access private
 */
    function __clean() {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $this->__cleaned = stripslashes($this->__tainted);
        } else {
            $this->__cleaned = $this->__tainted;
        }

        $this->__cleaned = str_replace(array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;"), array("&amp;amp;", "&amp;lt;", "&amp;gt;"), $this->__cleaned);
        $this->__cleaned = preg_replace('#(&\#*\w+)[\x00-\x20]+;#u', "$1;", $this->__cleaned);
        $this->__cleaned = preg_replace('#(&\#x*)([0-9A-F]+);*#iu', "$1$2;", $this->__cleaned);
        $this->__cleaned = html_entity_decode($this->__cleaned, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
        $this->__cleaned = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+[\x00-\x20\"\'\/])(on|xmlns)[^>]*>#iUu', "$1>", $this->__cleaned);
        $this->__cleaned = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20]*=[\x00-\x20]*([\`\'\"]*)[\\x00-\x20]*j[\x00-\x20]*a[\x00-\x20]*v[\x00-\x20]*a[\x00-\x20]*s[\x00-\x20]*c[\x00-\x20]*r[\x00-\x20]*i[\x00-\x20]*p[\x00-\x20]*t[\x00-\x20]*:#iUu', '$1=$2nojavascript...', $this->__cleaned);
        $this->__cleaned = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20]*=([\'\"]*)[\x00-\x20]*v[\x00-\x20]*b[\x00-\x20]*s[\x00-\x20]*c[\x00-\x20]*r[\x00-\x20]*i[\x00-\x20]*p[\x00-\x20]*t[\x00-\x20]*:#iUu', '$1=$2novbscript...', $this->__cleaned);
        $this->__cleaned = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20]*=*([\'\"]*)[\x00-\x20]*-moz-binding[\x00-\x20]*:#iUu','$1=$2nomozbinding...', $this->__cleaned);
        $this->__cleaned = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20]*=([\'\"]*)[\x00-\x20]*data[\x00-\x20]*:#Uu', '$1=$2nodata...', $this->__cleaned);
        $this->__cleaned = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+)style[\x00-\x20]*=[\x00-\x20]*([\`\'\"]*).*expression[\x00-\x20]*\([^>]*>#iU', "$1>", $this->__cleaned);
        $this->__cleaned = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+)style[\x00-\x20]*=[\x00-\x20]*([\`\'\"]*).*behaviour[\x00-\x20]*\([^>]*>#iU', "$1>", $this->__cleaned);
        $this->__cleaned = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+)style[\x00-\x20]*=[\x00-\x20]*([\`\'\"]*).*s[\x00-\x20]*c[\x00-\x20]*r[\x00-\x20]*i[\x00-\x20]*p[\x00-\x20]*t[\x00-\x20]*:*[^>]*>#iUu', "$1>", $this->__cleaned);
        $this->__cleaned = preg_replace('#</*\w+:\w[^>]*>#i', "", $this->__cleaned);
        do {
            $oldstring = $this->__cleaned;
            $this->__cleaned = preg_replace('#</*(applet|meta|xml|blink|link|style|script|embed|object|iframe|frame|frameset|ilayer|layer|bgsound|title|base)[^>]*>#i', "", $this->__cleaned);
        } while ($oldstring != $this->__cleaned);
        $this->__cleaned = str_replace(array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;"), array("&amp;amp;", "&amp;lt;", "&amp;gt;"), $this->__cleaned);
    }
}
```

just what i want to say, such long regexes on big htmls can really cause good slowdown.

Check the above things and get back to us, so we can investigate this deeply.

Comment: I've run X-debug and have an output file for a sample page. Can I upload it somewhere? I used webgrind to view it..

The routing costs resources; I just baked a default Blog Application in a fresh installation of CakePHP 1.3 & 2.0. CPU still spikes when accessing Any page! Have tried this on multiple PCs..

Comment: Will check the regexes. Thanks :)

Comment: 60% cpu is too much for framework with basic blog app. You may prefer to switch to CodeIgniter, but Yii eats even less than code igniter, while may still work a bit slower. Anyways both of them are great MVCs.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear..Its upto 60% with many Html->links on my custom app. On the default app, there's a 10-15% hike on Every CakePHP request on httpd.exe while normal PHP pages dont seem to use 'anything'..

Comment: Even 10% load on server it is tooo high. If you believe cakephp is good MVC -> review the code and data structure, else switch to another